# Installing ng-mouseover and ng-mouseout cause highly inefficient AngularJS code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I realize when I install `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseout` event callback, my entire AngularJS becomes very slow.

Soon, I realize the 2 callbacks, will cause other AngularJS functions being re-evaluate again and again, by just moving the mouse around.

### HTML code

```
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl"
  ng-mouseover="onScreen($event)"
  ng-mouseout="offScreen($event)">

  <div id="dummy"
    ng-show="isLoggedIn()">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### controllers.js

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];

  $scope.onScreen = function (e) {
  };

  $scope.offScreen = function (e) {
  };

  $scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
      console.log("isLoggedIn : " + new Date().getTime());
      return true;
  };
});
```

In the above example, `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseout` just simply call empty functions. However, if I try to move my mouse over the browser, I will realize `isLoggedIn` is being triggered multiple times.

May I know why AngularJS has such behavior? How can I avoid such?

Comment: That is pretty much expected. What are you actually doing inside mouseover/mouseout events?

Comment: To handle sliding menu. May I know why do you think this is an expected behavior?

Comment: Any luck with my answer yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is very much expected behavior:

- mouseover/mouseout events bubble up (see [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)) the DOM tree. Meaning even if you hover over anything inside your page (inside the body tag ofcourse), it will bubble up and run the mouseover/mouseout event handlers registered on the body.
- Angular runs all the watchers ([digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)) in order to update any DOM bindings on the view to reflect any changes to the scope properties as these [events gets triggered](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L69) via `scope.$apply()`.
- Previous step causes `isLoggedIn()` expression @ `ng-show="isLoggedIn()"` to be evaluated again as ng-show directive creates a watcher as well.

Instead, if applicable use `mouseenter/mouseleave` as these events do not bubble up and will just run when you focus on the page and out.

```
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl"
     ng-mouseenter="onScreen($event)"
     ng-mouseleave="offScreen($event)">
```

Another thing is to avoid binding function expression in angular binding as far as possible, try to bind to property instead.

Example: You should set `$scope.status.isLoggedIn` wherever applicable and use that flag in `ng-show` @ `ng-show="status.isLoggedIn"`. And ofcourse if you really need to prevent any digest from happening, create your custom directive instead of `ng-mouseenter/leave` and perform the sliding menu display there. That is you have to do it manually instead of  what angular does for you via DOM scope bindings.